# How do you keep an iterable alive to keep pulling from it?

Tags: dart, infinite-scroll

I was looking at the https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/codelab tutorial for dart, and I noticed that they kept recalling their iterator. I wanted to keep the iterator around, and just continue to pull from it, so I worked up this:

```
class _FunPageState extends State<FunPage> {
  final _things = <Widget>[];
  late Iterable<Widget> _funPuller;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _funPuller = generateFunThings();
  }
  Iterable<Widget> generateFunThings() sync*{
    int i=1;
    while (true) {
      yield Text("$i");
      i += 1;
    }
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => ListView.builder(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      if (index.isOdd) {
        return const Divider();
      }
      index = (index/2).floor();
      if (index >= _things.length) {
        _things.addAll(_funPuller.take(2));
      }
      return _things[index];
    },
  );
}
```

Except I noticed that this just generated the list `1,2,1,2,1,2,...` rather than `1,2,3,4,5,...` as I expected. Is there a way I can get the result of `generateFunThings()` to  persist so I can continue calling it?

Comment: You have an [`Iterable`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/Iterable-class.html) mixed up with an [`Iterator`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/Iterator-class.html).  An `Iterable` is just a collection that can be iterated over; a `List` is a subclass of `Iterable`, and you (probably) wouldn't expect `list.take(2)` to mutate `list` by permanently consuming 2 elements from it.  You instead want an `Iterator`.  Unfortunately, the `Iterator` API is (IMO) awkward to use.